Why is the formula for compound interest the way it is?
I understand the compound interest formula when it only involves compounding yearly at a certain rate, but I do not understand the concept of compounding within a year.
For example, if the investment is 1000 dollars, the interest rate is 8% per annum and is being compounded monthly, the formula to calculate the investment is:
$$A= 1000*(1+\frac{8}{1200})^{12x}$$
However, this formula does not make sense to me because if I was the bank and if an investor deposits 1000 dollars and states the rate is 8% per annum, they are going to compound it monthly and withdraw it after 5 years. Then I would assume that they would like to compound it monthly for some arbitrary reason and by then end of the 5 years, the investment would be equal to the investment that is compounded yearly.
Therefore, the formula that I expected for the monthly compounding investment would look like this:
$$A = 1000*(1+k)^{12x}$$
Where 'k' is the monthly interest rate.
If I am assuming that the investment compounded monthly must equal to the investment compounded yearly, then to find the monthly interest rate, I would write this equation:
$$1000*(1+k)^{12x} = 1000*(1+\frac{8}{100})^{x}$$
And after solving for 'k', I get that the monthly interest rate is ≈ 0.00643
However, in the actual compound interest formula, the monthly interest rate would be r/12. I don't understand what the purpose of such an equation is. If they wanted the investment to compound so that it exceeds the annual compounding investment (at year > 0) and if they wanted the monthly rate to simply be r/12, then why can't they simply say that? I don't understand if I am not understanding the concept due to me lacking mathematical intuition or if it is simply because that's just how the situation is.
Can someone please clarify my misunderstanding?

Not sure what you are asking.  Yes, it can be confusing when rates are quoted without clearly specifying details (like day count, compounding periods, and so on).  And, yes, people tend to quote "annualized" rates which then must be rescaled to handle different time intervals.  Is that what you are asking?

I understand that the rates must be rescaled, but is the situation simply that if the rate is 'r' and if the investment is being compounded monthly, then is the monthly rate simply r/12? I am getting confused because I don't understand the purpose of compound interest. Does the investor simply want to compound it frequently but expect the withdrawal amount to be equal to the withdrawal amount when the investment is compounded annually? Or do they want the investment to compound at a rate of (r/12)% so that the withdrawal amount is much higher?

If their intention is to ensure that the investment compounds monthly and that the withdrawal amount should be equal to the withdrawal amount when the investment is compounded annually, then the monthly interest rate would not be'r/12'. I understand that my question is confusing, so feel free to ask any more questions.

The bank's conventions are perfectly clear, so I don't see what you are asking.  Yes, they could quote $\frac r{12}$ instead of $r$...but so what?  It's at least somewhat useful to have "all" rates quoted annually.  After all, there's nothing special about monthly compound intervals.  Daily, quarterly, semi-annually, and annually are also commonly used.  At least quoting all of them annually gives some sense of how to compare them.

In your first equation, where you wrote $\dfrac8{12}$, did you mean $\dfrac{.08}{12}$ or $\dfrac8{1200}$?

Worth noting:  In Finance, one gets in the habit of rewriting everything in terms of some fixed rate of return units.  There are, after all, far more complicated situations than simple compounding and it is necessary to have some way to compare returns.

I meant (8/12)/100. I will correct it. Sorry for the confusion.

@lulu so, is it simply a convention to make the monthly rate or any rate within a year simply (r/n) [where n is the number of periods within a year]? The reason why I got confused was because I don't understand the intent of the investor. If the rate is simply (r/n), then I guess their intent is to take advantage of exponentiation to ensure that their withdrawal amount is higher than the withdrawal if they simply compounded monthly.

The more frequently interest is compounded, the greater the return (for the same annual rate)

"Intent" really isn't the issue here.  The bank won't let you choose the compounding intervals (at least, not without also changing the nominal rate of interest).  Mathematically, it would be best to think about continuous compounding.  The math is simpler.  But in practice, interest is credited to accounts at fixed intervals of time.

@lulu What I was asking is that is it simply a convention to make the monthly rate or any rate within a year simply (r/n) [where n is the number of periods within a year]? The reason why I got confused was because I don't understand the intent of the investor. If the rate is simply (r/n), then I guess their intent is to take advantage of exponentiation to ensure that their withdrawal amount is higher than the withdrawal if they simply compounded monthly.

So I was saying that if the intent of the investor is to not take advantage of exponentiation and they are compounding within a year for some arbitrary reason and they also want to ensure that their withdrawal after compounding monthly should be equal to their withdrawal after compounding annually, then the monthly rate would not be (r/12/100). It would be a value that allows the withdrawal amounts to equal each other. By a different value, I meant that like in my previous equation, how the rate is k, which is approximately equal to 0.00643.

Therefore, in summary, my question is that: is the intent of the investor to simply take advantage of exponentiation? and is the convention simply that the period rate is (r/n/100), where n is the number of periods within a year?

Again, forget "intent".  It's not relevant.  The cash flow is the cash flow.  It is set by the bank, not by the investor, though the investor may have some options.  Banks set "nominal" rates to give a sense of the interest.  The details depend on the investment.  If the account has monthly compounding, then the effective rate for the month is (roughly) the nominal rate divided by $12$.  "roughly" because the details of day counting may (or may not matter).  If quarterly compounding, then divide by $4$ and so on.

A rational investor might prefer to receive interest more frequently, but typically this makes little difference.  The bank adjusts the nominal rate to make the total returns comparable.    What does make a difference is the duration of the investment.  Typically, banks will pay a higher nominal rate if you agree to leave the funds with them longer.   In effect, you are being paid to forego any good investment opportunities that might come up.  But that's not a compounding issue.

@lulu , so the period rate being (r/n/100) is simply the convention. And like you said it is set by the bank. Am I correct?

Yes, that's how banks quote nominal rates.

@lulu , thank you for your patience and commitment towards helping me understand this concept. Your answer clarified my misunderstanding.
